# How to compare a multi-column delimited file to a single-column file and delete "common" lines?

Tags: text-processing

I have 2 files, one which contains only one column, and another which contains several `|`-delimited columns. I need to compare file 1 with file 2 and delete common lines, and copy them to a new file.

A "common" line is a line where column 7 of `file2` is equal to the (single) value in `file1`.

- file1:

  ```
  12345
  89457
  34890
  ```
- file2:

  ```
  GTDtech
  rachel|USA|00|34|ty|ES|12345|789900098|tye
  FLPEN|MAL|90|45|tui|FE|34890|883562748|yu
  ahnat|jap|88|91|hb|kl|24424|784284141|fwfhnw
  ```

Comment: how do you want to compare the files?   the only connection I can see between them is that `12345` in line 1 of file1 matches `12345` in column 7 of line 2 in file2, and  34890 is in file1 and colum 7 of the third line of file2.   Is that what you want to do? compare the lines in file1 with column 7 of file2?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, since your files are completely differently formatted, it is completely unclear what a "common line" between those two might look like. Please edit your post to include (at least) the expected output for your input example. Also, include what you already tried, and where you failed. Otherwise you may get answers that you already know won't work.

Comment: yes we need to compare the column 7 in second file with the column  in file 1 these 2 are identical

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=1; next}; ! ($7 in a)' file1 file2
GTDtech
ahnat|jap|88|91|hb|kl|24424|784284141|fwfhnw
```

This reads in file1, and creates an element in array `a` for each line.  Then it reads in file2, printing any line where column 7 is **NOT** in array `a`.